# Intersection of sorted numpy arrays

Tags: numpy

I have a list of sorted numpy arrays. What is the most efficient way to compute the sorted intersection of these arrays?

In my application, I expect the number of arrays to be less than 10^4, I expect the individual arrays to be of length less than 10^7, and I expect the length of the intersection to be close to p*N, where N is the length of the largest array and where 0.99 < p <= 1.0. The arrays are loaded from disk and can be loaded in batches if they won't all fit in memory at once.

A quick and dirty approach is to repeatedly invoke `numpy.intersect1d()`. That seems inefficient though as `intersect1d()` does not take advantage of the fact that the arrays are sorted.

Comment: What are the range of numbers? Are they only integers? Are they only positive?

Comment: They are positive 64-bit integers.

Comment: What's their range? Is it known beforehand? Also, are they unique within each array?

Comment: They represent timestamps within the past year, in nanoseconds. They are unique within each range.

Comment: How are the arrays stored now?  Each one file on disk?

Comment: There is one hdf5 file storing each array in a separate dataset.

Comment: One approach--Instead of creating a potentially huge list of arrays, read each dataset incrementally.  Begin with an intersection of the first two arrays (call this `un`), find the intersection of this with the third array; overwrite `un` with that smaller intersection and overwrite the third array with the fourth, and so on.  This may help with memory issues.

Comment: how intersection can have roughly the same size than the biggest array?  it must be shorter than the smallest.

Comment: @B.M. The intersection will have the same size as the biggest array if all the arrays are identical.

Comment: So the arrays are almost identical?

Comment: Yes, they are very similar.

Comment: @BradSolomon And how do I compute the intersection of two sorted arrays efficiently? Do I have to write some cython to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `intersect1d` sort arrays each time, it's effectively inefficient.

Here you have to sweep intersection and each sample together to build the new intersection, which can be done in linear time, maintaining order.

Such task must often be tuned by hand with low level routines.

Here a way to do that with `numba` :

```
from numba import njit
import numpy as np

@njit
def drop_missing(intersect,sample):
    i=j=k=0
    new_intersect=np.empty_like(intersect)
    while i< intersect.size and j < sample.size:
            if intersect[i]==sample[j]: # the 99% case
                new_intersect[k]=intersect[i]
                k+=1
                i+=1
                j+=1
            elif intersect[i]<sample[j]:
                i+=1
            else : 
                j+=1
    return new_intersect[:k]
```

Now the samples :

```
n=10**7
ref=np.random.randint(0,n,n)  
ref.sort()

def perturbation(sample,k):
    rands=np.random.randint(0,n,k-1)
    rands.sort()
    l=np.split(sample,rands)
    return np.concatenate([a[:-1] for a in l])

samples=[perturbation(ref,100) for  _ in range(10)] #similar samples
```

And a run for 10 samples

```
def find_intersect(samples):
    intersect=samples[0]
    for sample in samples[1:]:
        intersect=drop_missing(intersect,sample)
    return intersect                

In [18]: %time u=find_intersect(samples)
Wall time: 307 ms

In [19]: len(u)
Out[19]: 9999009
```

This way it seems that the job can be done in about 5 minutes , beyond loading time.

Answer (score 2):

A few months ago, I wrote a C++-based python extension for this exact purpose. The [package](https://gitlab.sauerburger.com/frank/sortednp) is called `sortednp` and is available via pip. The intersection of multiple sorted numpy arrays, for example, `a`, `b` and `c`,  can be calculated with

```
import sortednp as snp
i = snp.kway_intersect(a, b, c)
```

By default, this uses an [exponential search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_search) to advance the array indices internally which is pretty fast in cases where the intersection is small. In your case, it might be faster if you add `algorithm=snp.SIMPLE_SEARCH` to the method call.