More efficient ways of finding common values from multiple lists of arrays
I want to find a more efficient way of finding common values from a set of arrays. Say I have three lists of arrays:
list_1 = [np.array([1, 2, 3]), np.array([]), np.array([4, 5, 6])]
list_2 = [np.array([2, 3, 6], np.array([1, 2, 3]), np.array([4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])]
list_3 = [np.array([5, 2, 3, 7]), np.array([7, 8, 9]), np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])]

What I want to get is another list of arrays of common elements from each index:
out = [np.array([2, 3]), np.array([]), np.array([4, 5, 6])]

Currently I am doing this using:
common_vals = []
for index in range(len(list_1)):
    common_elements = reduce(np.intersect1d, (list_1[index], list_2[index], list_3[index])
    common_vals.append(common_elements)

Which is quite slow when the length of list_1 can be a couple of thousand items, and the number of lists is large.
A test set could be created by:
from random import random

list_1, list_2, list_3 = [], [], []
for i in range(10_000):
    length_1 = random.randint(0, 1000)
    list_1.append(np.array(set([random.randint(0,1000) for _ in range(length_1)])))
    length_2 = random.randint(0, 1000)
    list_2.append(np.array(set([random.randint(0,1000) for _ in range(length_2)])))
    length_3 = random.randint(0, 1000)
    list_3.append(np.array(set([random.randint(0,1000) for _ in range(length_3)])))

[Clarification]
The lists of arrays are lists of indices so the numbers will always be integers. They are ordered and need to maintain that order and will always be the same length. So the first list of the output of common items should be the common items from index 1 of each of the input lists. Each item in the inputs lists of lists will be unique so in the final output list they should appear once.

Are the values in the lists guaranteed to be integers and are there any bounds on the values that they can take? If the maximum value is not too large then representing each item in the list(s) as a bit position in a bitset is hard to beat. Common values in all the lists are then the logical bitwise and of the various bitset variables.

All values in the list will be integers (they are lists of indexes). There are no hard bounds as the indexes depend on previous calculation which can range from 1_000 to 1_000_000_000 and even larger

You pasted an example where "common values" are always exact subslices of the items, and where values do not repeat. Can you make the requirements? e g: are the lists ordered or unordered ? should an element that is repeated twice in all list be present twice in the final list ?

perhaps this could help : https://stackoverflow.com/q/46572308/86072 ?

In each list in the final common values list, items should be unique. The lists of lists are ordered and so the final common_values list needs to reflect the order of the input lists (i.e. the first list in common values should reflect the common values in the first list of all input lists). In each list in common values each unique item should only appear once. Should also be clarified in the question above as well now.

@Philip09 can you provide more details on the required order of the output?

@mozway what do you mean? The order of the output in each list (so each list in out) does not matter, the order of the lists in the list does matter.

@Philip09 got it, then the original set approach should work fine. My alternative approach keeps the order in the sublists if that had been important.

I can see your solution works fine on my test case (the one in the question) much faster than my original solution (3x in line with your findings), but when I apply it to my actual workflow the speed increase isn't necessarily there and I'm not sure why. Trying to figure that out currently.

@mozway so I'm not seeing the speed improvements because the input lists are lists of arrays not lists of lists....my bad

Also can an array have a repeated value? or are the values in an array strictly unique? ie already a set but just in an array format? Your test case have repeated elements in them

The array should have unique values @onyambu

The problem is that in your test cases, the way you generated the arrays does not guarantee to have unique values

Edited to have sets. The original question used lists which was fine (hence the answers were faster).

I doubt numpy will be much help here. The easiest way to do this, IMO, is to employ Python's sets. Transpose the list of lists to obtain list of columns, turn elements of each column into sets, and run set.intersection on them.
lists = [list_1, list_2, list_3]
intersections = [set.intersection(*[set(x) for x in col]) for col in zip(*lists)]
print(intersections)
# => [{2, 3}, set(), {4, 5, 6}]


What about using a set intersection?:
[set.intersection(*map(set, x)) for x in zip(list_1, list_2, list_3)]

Output:
[{2, 3}, set(), {4, 5, 6}]

timings
(Using your larger test set)
# numpy
1.92 s ± 113 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

# set intersection
801 ms ± 104 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

ordered intersection
I realized from one of your comments that you would like to keep the original order of the items.
You can tweak the above code to first get a set, then use that to filter one of the lists (e.g. the first):
def ordered_intersection(it):
    S = set.intersection(*map(set, it))
    return [x for x in it[0] if x in S]

out = [ordered_intersection(x) for x in zip(list_1, list_2, list_3)]

Output:
[[2, 3], [], [4, 5, 6]]


Ten seconds... :D

@Amadan Sorry! But great minds think alike ;)
